# python how to use groupby for classify data and calculate other column's mean

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe as below. I want to use 'part1' column as the benchmark for classify the data to 3 parts(each part has same number dataset) and calculate the mean of each group's part2's mean. Such as row0 and row1 as groupB and the mean is (0.67+(-0.03))/2.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date":["20130101","20130101","20130103","20130103","20130105","20130105"],
    "part1":[0.5,0.7,1.3,1.5,0.1,0.3],
    "part2":[0.67,-0.03,1.95,-3.25,-0.3,0.6]
})
    date    part1   part2   output
0   20130101    0.5 0.67    0.32
1   20130101    0.7 -0.03   0.32
2   20130103    1.3 1.95    -0.65
3   20130103    1.5 -3.25   -0.65
4   20130105    0.1 -0.3    0.15
5   20130105    0.3 0.6 0.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to calculate the mean of per day,you can use `groupby` as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date":["20130101","20130101","20130103","20130103","20130105","20130105"],
    "part1":[0.5,0.7,1.3,1.5,0.1,0.3],
    "part2":[0.67,-0.03,1.95,-3.25,-0.3,0.6]
})
df.groupby("date").mean().reset_index()
```

the result:

```
       date  part1  part2
0  20130101    0.6   0.32
1  20130103    1.4  -0.65
2  20130105    0.2   0.15
```

Comment: Thanks. But you misunderstand my questions. Groupby not by the 'date' , but by the value of part1.

Comment: yes,but if goupby 'part1',you will get six groups.you want this?
```
df.groupby("part1").mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: no. the part1 value can be divided into 3 parts according to their value. After classifying, the calculate the mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `pandas`, if you have your data in `df`:

```
def foo(x,n=3):
    df = x.copy()
    bins = np.quantile(df['part1'],np.linspace(0,1,n+1))
    df['tmp'] = 0
    for i in range(n):
        idx = (df['part1'] > bins[i]) & (df['part1'] <= bins[i+1])
        df['tmp'][idx] = i
    return df.groupby('tmp').agg({'part2':'mean'})

foo(df)
```

will separate from quantiles so it **guarantees** that each group will have **same number of elements**. Group by `tmp` will get those groups and calculate mean of `part2` of each group:

```
     part2
tmp       
0     0.15
1     0.32
2    -0.65
```

Comment: Thanks. But it has little problem. If I have 10 data. It divided into 5 parts, every part has 2 data. But in your code, it cuts data into 5 parts, but each part may have 2 or 1 or none data or more.

Comment: This answer is what you've asked for, or maybe you should clarify your question further and exemplify (in a reproducible way) if possible.

Comment: For example, 0.5,0.7,1.3,1.5,0.1,0.3 should be divided into (0.1,0.3),(0.5,0.7),(1.3,1.5), each group has two elments. But in your code, it is (0.1,0.3,0.5),(0.7),(1.3,1.5)

Comment: Okay, I changed the code to have groups with same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function for the `by` argument of panda's `groupby` method.

```py
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date":["20130101","20130101","20130103","20130103","20130105","20130105"],
    "part1":[0.5,0.7,1.3,1.5,0.1,0.3],
    "part2":[0.67,-0.03,1.95,-3.25,-0.3,0.6]
})


def grouper(df, val):
    foo = df.iloc[val]['part1']
    if foo > 0.0 and foo < 0.4:
         return 0
    elif foo > 0.3 and foo < 1.0:
         return 1
    elif foo > 1.0:
         return 2

grouped = df['part2'].groupby(by=partial(grouper, df)).mean()
```

This results in

```
1    0.15
2    0.32
3   -0.65
Name: part2, dtype: float64
```